# SignalR call asp.net method for all clients?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, signalr

I made a simple chat app. I am impressed by signalR.

My question is, does this technology give us an ability to call asp.net server side methods (for example ones in aspx.cs backend) ?

Let me explain you what I am talking about. I have a WCF service which retrieves data from database and sends it to client. On client side, there is a method getCars(), which is called on page_Load and shows all cars to the user.

But for example if other client changes the cars and sends changes to WCF service, service updates new data to database. So is there an option to get this changes shown to other people with SignalR..

Like normal SignalR sendMessage works.. Some client sends message to server, and server adds message to all clients, is there a possibility to to the same with ASP.NET method for ALL clients with signalR (when one client invokes changes in database to call that method again fro ALL clients)?

I heard this is done with Duplex with WCF but I am interested if it is possible with SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, since you are using the JavaScript client, when the client do a change you call the server

```
commandHubProxy.invoke('InformClients').done(function (result) {
            //Call Succeeded
        }).fail(function (error) {
            //log error
        });
```

And on the server, the method informs the rest of the clients

```
    public void InformClients(string text)
    {
        Clients.Others.DataUpdated();
    }
```

Then on the other clients you can do an Ajax request to refresh the data

```
commandHubProxy.on('DataUpdated', function () {
            //Refresh the data or inform the user
        });
```